# Mysql stored procedure multiple selects

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select

I am running a stored procedure.  The issue seems to be that it will go into the if statement.  Also for some reason or another regardless of how many selects I use it will only return the first.  I've copied this from another stored procedure that works like a charm, but this one just won't go.  Any ideas?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS genSelPriceTier;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE genSelPriceTier(tier_id INT, default_id INT)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE rowCount INT DEFAULT 0;  
          SELECT * FROM price_tier WHERE price_tier_id = tier_id;
          SET rowCount = FOUND_ROWS();
        IF rowCount < 1 THEN
            SELECT * FROM price_tier WHERE price_tier_id = default_id;
            END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1468) reported related to the usage of FOUND_ROWS(). So, I recommend using Count(*) for the number of rows returned. Something like the following should work.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS genSelPriceTier;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE genSelPriceTier(tier_id INT, default_id INT)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE rowCount INT DEFAULT 0;  
          SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rowCount FROM price_tier WHERE price_tier_id = tier_id 
        IF rowCount < 1 THEN
            SELECT * FROM price_tier WHERE price_tier_id = default_id;
            END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Yes certianly less than 1 or rowCount = 0 would work, but sorry to say this answer does not work either.  Very perplexed

Comment: There is no error, it just doesn't go into the If statement and return the second select if nothing is found in the first select e.g. if rowCount returns a value les than 1

Comment: Looking at it more it must be returning a value higher than 1 in the found rows.  I only have 2 recored in the DB id 1 and 2 respectively.  so if I pass (0,2) i should return record 2 as the default but it does not

Comment: I've edited my answer - added a limit for no rows to be returned which might be required for FOUND_ROWS() to work correctly. Can you try this?

Comment: I have and still no dice.  Strange thing is i'm running the following in another stored procedure and it works

                        SELECT
    hit_date
   FROM
    hit_counter
   WHERE
    page = this_page AND
    site = this_site AND
    hit_date = CURDATE();
   SET rowCount = FOUND_ROWS();
   IF rowCount < 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO
     hit_counter
     (hit_date,
     site,
     page,
     hits)
    VALUES
     (CURDATE(),
     this_site,
     this_page,
     1);
   ELSE

Comment: Does you found_rows() return 1? Did you test it? Edit if part and modify it like this for test: if `rowCount < 1 THEN` ....

Comment: No doesn't return 1, event upon trying "SELECT ROW_COUNT()" as the last thing in my procedure it still returns the first select even if I delete everything out and put three selects one right after another it still returns the first as opposed to the last

Comment: Apparently, there is a bug situation with the usage of FOUND_ROWS(). That may be the reason for the pain we have been through. Therefore I have changed my answer. Count(*) is realiable for calculating the no rows returned.

Comment: Yes I thought this too, but I think the rows is returning correctly, What I believe is going on is the first select statement is returned regardless of what you do afterwards.

Comment: I couldn't understand the current problem here. What do you mean by  first select statement is returned regardless of what you do afterwards?

Comment: example
BEGIN
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
 SELECT * FROM TABLE2;
END

retrun the result set from table1

Comment: It seems that I will have to use a "SELECT INSERT INTO" a temporary table and then use a single select from that to obtain the correct result set